# How to create subsystem via CLI in JBoss 7.1 standalone.xml config

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Is there a way to create a `<subsystem>` tag in the standalone.xml file using JBoss CLI?

Specifically, I would like to add the following line:

`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:snowdrop:1.0"/>`

to the `<profile>` element as per https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SNOWDROP/The+Spring+Deployer.

Best,
Kamil